# Match words not beginning with certain character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to mark and replace words that do not start with # from a text. The text file looks like this:

```
Some words #word #anotherword #etc
Some more words #words #anotherword #etc #etc more words here
No words containing that character in this line
Etc
```

What should be matched:

```
Some words 
Some more words                           more words here
No words containing that character in this line
Etc
```

I am totally new to regex and have been trying to come up with the right code. The closest i got is marking all the text excluding the # only, not the word attached to it as well. The part after the # shouldn't be selected. Note: special characters and numbers also exist and should be marked, but not the ones after the #. How do i accomplish this the simplest way?

Comment: I suspect you want to remove all text but matches, right? Then use `(#\S+)|(?s).` (or `\B(#\S+)|(?s).`) and replace with `(?1$1\n)`

Comment: `(?<!#)\b\w+` matches words not preceeded by `#`, is that what you want?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: unfortunately both codes select the whole text.

Comment: What do you mean? Share the expected output for the above text

Comment: @Toto - it works! But for some reason special characters are not matched. For example: - some word. The "-" is not matched.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56289683/edit) and add more test cases.

Comment: How about: `(?:^|\s)\K(?!#)\S+`

Comment: @Toto - that's what i exactly needed! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)[^\s#]\S*
```

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - whitespace char or start of string must come right before the current location
- `[^\s#]` - any char but whitespace and `#`
- `\S*` - any 0+ non-whitespace chars.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VGjcta/1).